# Boost transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, group-theory

I have a boost defined as

$$L = \exp(\alpha \hat{n} \cdot \vec{K}), \quad \hat{n}^2=1, \quad \tanh\alpha = - \frac{v}{c}$$

where

$$K_{1} = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right), \quad K_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right), \quad K_{3}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right).$$

I wanted to show that transformation of every boost could be written as

$$L = 1 + (\hat{n} \cdot \vec{K})\; \sinh \alpha + (\cosh \alpha - 1)(\hat{n} \cdot \vec{K})^2.$$

I don't know how to show this.

Comment: Do you know how the exponential of a matrix is defined?

Comment: [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation)

Comment: Check the identity for $K_1$ and next use the action of rotations on the boost vectors.

Comment: If you have some practice with Pauli matrices, you can use the fact that $\sigma_1\oplus 0 =K_1$ and $\sigma_1^2=I$….

Comment: **Hint :** Replace $\:x\:$ by $\:(\alpha \hat{n} \cdot \vec{K})\:$ in 
$$
e^x=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{m=\infty}\dfrac{x^m}{m!}=\dfrac{\cosh x+\sinh x}{2}
$$
and try to find what about the powers $\:(\alpha \hat{n} \cdot \vec{K})^m=\alpha^m(\hat{n} \cdot \vec{K})^m\:$.